# I get ajax Requested page not found error what is wrong with this

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http-status-code-404

When I do a POST I always get the 'Requested page not found. [404]', I cant figure out whats´wrong please advice

I have this [web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) project that works great and now I modify it, remove database and add custom `ControllerBase` instead.
But I get the [404] error somethings missing ..

here is my code

JavaScript

```
const uri = "api/book";
let todos = null;
function getCount(data) {
    const el = $("#counter");
    let name = "to-do";
    if (data) {
        if (data > 1) {
            name = "to-dos";
        }
        el.text(data + " " + name);
    } else {
        el.text("No " + name);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: uri,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            const tBody = $("#todos");

            $(tBody).empty();

            getCount(data.length);

            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                const tr = $("<tr></tr>")
                    .append(
                        $("<td></td>").append(
                            $("<input/>", {
                                type: "checkbox",
                                disabled: true,
                                checked: item.isComplete
                            })
                        )
                    )
                    .append($("<td></td>").text(item.name))
                    .append(
                        $("<td></td>").append(
                            $("<button>Edit</button>").on("click", function () {
                                editItem(item.id);
                            })
                        )
                    )
                    .append(
                        $("<td></td>").append(
                            $("<button>Delete</button>").on("click", function () {
                                deleteItem(item.id);
                            })
                        )
                    );

                tr.appendTo(tBody);
            });

            todos = data;
        }
    });
}

function addItem() {
    const item = {
        name: $("#add-name").val(),
        isComplete: false
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        accepts: "application/json",
        url: uri,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ///alert("Something went wrong!");
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            alert(msg);
            ///$('#post').html(msg);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            getData();
            $("#add-name").val("");
        }
    });
}

function deleteItem(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri + "/" + id,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function (result) {
            getData();
        }
    });
}

function editItem(id) {
    $.each(todos, function (key, item) {
        if (item.id === id) {
            $("#edit-name").val(item.name);
            $("#edit-id").val(item.id);
            $("#edit-isComplete")[0].checked = item.isComplete;
        }
    });
    $("#spoiler").css({ display: "block" });
}

$(".my-form").on("submit", function () {
    const item = {
        name: $("#edit-name").val(),
        isComplete: $("#edit-isComplete").is(":checked"),
        id: $("#edit-id").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: uri + "/" + $("#edit-id").val(),
        type: "PUT",
        accepts: "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        success: function (result) {
            getData();
        }
    });

    closeInput();
    return false;
});

function closeInput() {
    $("#spoiler").css({ display: "none" });
}
```

My Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using WorkSampleBookSearch.Model;

namespace WorkSampleBookSearch
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BooksXmlController : ControllerBase
    {
        public BooksXmlController()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all items from PhoneBook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>PhoneBook items List</returns>
        // GET: api/Book
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetPhoneBookItems()
        {
            List<PhoneBookItem> PhoneBookItems = new List<PhoneBookItem>();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("phonebookitems")
                .Descendants("phonebookitem"))
            {
                PhoneBookItem phonebookitem = new PhoneBookItem
                {
                    /// Id 
                    /// Author
                    /// Title
                    /// Genre
                    /// Price
                    /// Publish_date
                    /// Description
                    Id = element.Element("id").Value,
                    Author = element.Element("author").Value,
                    Title = element.Element("title").Value,
                    Genre = element.Element("genre").Value,
                    Price = element.Element("price").Value,
                    Publish_date = element.Element("publish_date").Value,
                    Description = element.Element("description").Value
                };

                PhoneBookItems.Add(phonebookitem);
                PhoneBookItems = PhoneBookItems.OrderBy(p => p.Title).ToList();
            }

            return Ok(PhoneBookItems);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a PhoneBook item matching the given id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id of item to be retrieved</param>
        /// <returns>PhoneBook item</returns>
        // GET: api/Book/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetPhoneBookItem(long id)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
            XElement element = doc.Element("phonebookitems").Elements("phonebookitem").
                Elements("id").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == id.ToString());

            XElement parent = element.Parent;

            PhoneBookItem phonebookitem = new PhoneBookItem
            {
                Id = element.Element("id").Value,
                Author = element.Element("author").Value,
                Title = element.Element("title").Value,
                Genre = element.Element("genre").Value,
                Price = element.Element("price").Value,
                Publish_date = element.Element("publish_date").Value,
                Description = element.Element("description").Value
            };
            return Ok(phonebookitem);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert a PhoneBook item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Inserts new PhoneBook item in books.xml and saves the file</returns>
        //POST: api/Book
        [HttpPost]
        public void PostPhoneBookItem(PhoneBookItem PhoneBookItem)
        {
            int maxId;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
            bool elementExist = doc.Descendants("phonebookitem").Any();
            if (elementExist)
            {
                maxId = doc.Descendants("phonebookitem").Max(x => (int)x.Element("id"));
            }
            else
            {
                maxId = 0;
            }
            /// Id 
            /// Author
            /// Title
            /// Genre
            /// Price
            /// Price
            /// Publish_date
            /// Description
            XElement root = new XElement("phonebookitem");
            root.Add(new XElement("id", maxId + 1));
            root.Add(new XElement("author", PhoneBookItem.Author));
            root.Add(new XElement("title", PhoneBookItem.Title));
            root.Add(new XElement("genre", PhoneBookItem.Genre));
            root.Add(new XElement("price", PhoneBookItem.Price));
            root.Add(new XElement("publish_date", PhoneBookItem.Publish_date));
            root.Add(new XElement("description", PhoneBookItem.Description));
            doc.Element("phonebookitems").Add(root);
            doc.Save("books.xml");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates a PhoneBook item matching the given id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id of item to be retrieved</param>
        /// <param name="PhoneBookItem">Retrieved PhoneBook item</param>
        /// <returns>Updates PhoneBook item in books.xml and saves the file</returns>
        //PUT: api/Book/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void PostPhoneBookItem(long id, PhoneBookItem PhoneBookItem)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");

            var items = from item in doc.Descendants("phonebookitem")
                        where item.Element("id").Value == id.ToString()
                        select item;

            foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
            {
                /// Id 
                /// Author
                /// Title
                /// Genre
                /// Price
                /// Publish_date
                /// Description
                itemElement.SetElementValue("author", PhoneBookItem.Author);
                itemElement.SetElementValue("title", PhoneBookItem.Title);
                itemElement.SetElementValue("genre", PhoneBookItem.Genre);
                itemElement.SetElementValue("price", PhoneBookItem.Price);
                itemElement.SetElementValue("publish_date", PhoneBookItem.Publish_date);
                itemElement.SetElementValue("description", PhoneBookItem.Description);

            }

            doc.Save("books.xml");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete a PhoneBook item matching the given id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id of item to be retrieved</param>
        /// <returns>Deletes item from books.xml and saves the file</returns>
        // DELETE: api/Book/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void DeletePhoneBookItem(long id)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
            var elementToDelete = from item in doc.Descendants("phonebookitem")
                                  where item.Element("id").Value == id.ToString()
                                  select item;

            elementToDelete.Remove();

            doc.Save("books.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my startup

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WorkSampleBookSearch
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }


            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the URI from

```
const uri = "api/book";
```

to

```
const uri = "api/booksxml";
```

Explanation:
`[Route("api/[controller]")]` means that the route will be be `api/controllerName` and in your case the name of the controller is `BooksXml` (the `Controller` suffix is not taken into consideration).